# Check with filename in two different directories(Unix)

Tags: unix

Say I have two different directories /root/dir1 & /root/dir2.
Dir1 has some files with .xls extension. I have to compare name of files(with .xls ext) in dir1 with name of files in dir2(.xls ext), if it matches then move corresponding file to dir3 and if doesn't matches then move the file to dir2.
Help me with the script in unix.

Comment: see here from a simple google. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/find-out-if-file-exists-with-conditional-expressions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
for f in $(comm -1 -2 <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2)); do cp dir1/$f dir3/; done
for f in $(comm -2 -3 <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2)); do cp dir1/$f dir2/; done
```

Comment: Hi,
It is working for me.Thanks.
Can you please suggest how to log it into a file if there is no xml file in "dir1".
As it will throw an error that dir doesnt exist.

Comment: You should be able to do: `if [ -f dir1/*.xls ]; then` ... (commands)`; fi`

Answer (score 0):

Tryout this:

```
for file in /dir1/*.xls
do
   if [ -f /dir2/$file ]
   then
       mv $file $dir3
   else
       mv $file $dir2
    fi
done
```